# BIND 9 master does not answer with additional section

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

We are running ISC BIND 9.14.3 64-bit on a Windows Server 2008 R2 behind NAT. It's the master server. There are three outsourced slave servers (don't know what DNS software are running). The slave servers are returning additional section even for out-of-zone records, but not the BIND master.

The options in named.conf are:

```
options {
  directory "c:\named";
  listen-on port 5353 { 192.168.4.12; };
  listen-on-v6 { none; };
  allow-query { any; };
  pid-file "etc\named.pid";
  recursion no;
  masterfile-format text;
  rrset-order { class IN type ANY name "*" order cyclic; };
  minimal-responses no;
  additional-from-auth yes;
  additional-from-cache yes;
};
```

Using `dig` to query the master server does not return additional sections:

```
[glm] c:\users\glm>dig mx gmeana.com @ns1.gmeana.net +additional

; <<>> DiG 9.14.3 <<>> mx gmeana.com @ns1.gmeana.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54714
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 094570b8eaebb8d9a7872bc35d1f1326e46b01808d9290db (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gmeana.com.                    IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
gmeana.com.             21600   IN      MX      30 mail2.gmeana.net.
gmeana.com.             21600   IN      MX      10 mail1.gmeana.net.
gmeana.com.             21600   IN      MX      20 mail3.gmeana.net.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
gmeana.com.             21600   IN      NS      ns3.gmeana.net.
gmeana.com.             21600   IN      NS      ns4.gmeana.net.
gmeana.com.             21600   IN      NS      ns1.gmeana.net.
gmeana.com.             21600   IN      NS      ns2.gmeana.net.

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 212.89.28.113#53(212.89.28.113)
;; WHEN: Fri Jul 05 11:06:46 Romance Daylight Time 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 215
```

Using `dig` to query any secondary does return additional section:

```
[glm] c:\users\glm>dig mx gmeana.com @ns2.gmeana.net +additional

; <<>> DiG 9.14.3 <<>> mx gmeana.com @ns2.gmeana.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34712
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 7
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gmeana.com.                    IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
gmeana.com.             21600   IN      MX      10 mail1.gmeana.net.
gmeana.com.             21600   IN      MX      20 mail3.gmeana.net.
gmeana.com.             21600   IN      MX      30 mail2.gmeana.net.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
gmeana.com.             21600   IN      NS      ns1.gmeana.net.
gmeana.com.             21600   IN      NS      ns2.gmeana.net.
gmeana.com.             21600   IN      NS      ns3.gmeana.net.
gmeana.com.             21600   IN      NS      ns4.gmeana.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
mail1.gmeana.net.       21600   IN      A       212.89.1.216
mail3.gmeana.net.       21600   IN      A       212.89.28.113
mail2.gmeana.net.       21600   IN      A       212.89.1.216
ns1.gmeana.net.         21600   IN      A       212.89.28.113
ns2.gmeana.net.         21600   IN      A       116.203.6.3
ns3.gmeana.net.         21600   IN      A       185.34.136.178
ns4.gmeana.net.         21600   IN      A       107.191.99.111

;; Query time: 51 msec
;; SERVER: 116.203.6.3#53(116.203.6.3)
;; WHEN: Fri Jul 05 11:07:56 Romance Daylight Time 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 288
```

I don't know what other configuration must be done in the BIND's `named.conf` in order to obtain responses with additional section.

Comment: I guess your secondaries are also configured as authoritative on `gmeana.net` but the primary is not? Because the primary response is totally valid and expected: if it is authoritative for `gmeana.com` only and if there are RR records for names in `gmeana.net` in the reply it has to do, it certainly MUST NOT put records for them as it is not authoritative for them.

Comment: The primary is authoritative for gmeana.net. dig soa gmeana.net @ns1.gmeana.net returns ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4

Comment: It works if recursion is allowed, but we don't want to expose to the Internet a recursive DNS server. The secondaries aren't recursives.

Comment: For clarity, is there any actual problem or mostly a question about why the response is different?

Comment: I'm wondering why the response is different, the master is working w/o any problem. BTW, I have enabled recursion and set forwarders to none. Now BIND is returning additional section and resolve queries only for their zones. Not a very elegant solution, IMHO.

Comment: I was wrong. After several retries with the same query the server resolves any zone. Shame on me.